# How to get error message from the scala/java MongoDB api

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, logging, casbah

I'm using Casbah (mongodb scala library). I have an insert that doesn't work.

```
val builder = MongoDBObject.newBuilder
builder += "_id" -> token.uuid
builder += "email" -> token.email
builder += "creationTime" -> token.creationTime
builder += "expirationTime" -> token.expirationTime
builder += "isSignUp" -> token.isSignUp
val writeResult = mycollection += (builder.result)
```

If I change this for something simpler (like, a simple {"hello": "world"} document), the insert is done. So I know there's something that doesn't work with this particular insert. However, I find no way to know why. I'd like to get some feedback from Mongo or from Casbah.

However the `WriteResult` class, which apparently comes directly from the Java MongoDB driver, seems very opaque: http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/WriteResult.html

How can I get some info about why an insert is failing? I'm not asking about this particular insert. Just, in general, how can I get info about the error that caused an insert to fail?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Casbah is a Scala wrapper over the Java MongoDB driver.

```
mycollection += (builder.result)
```

is translated into

```
mycollection.save(builder.result)
```

If the operation had an error it will throw an exception like described [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#save-com.mongodb.DBObject-).
The `WriteResult` containing information about the write if no error happened.

I would check:

1. `getN` and `isUpdateOfExisting` values in `WriteResult` because `save` is doing either update or insert (read more [here](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/WriteResult.html)).
2. `wasAcknowledged` value in `WriteResult` to make sure you get the exception and you don't have the `WriteConcern` set to `UNACKNOWLEDGED`.